# curl request doesn't return the user's data

Tags: curl, oauth-2.0, openid, saml-2.0, wso2-identity-server

As always I'm working on wso2 Identity Server.
So, by terminal I ask the access_token and til now everything fine.
But when I write the following curl request for having back the user's data:

> curl -k -H "Authorization: Bearer 4164157d677a6cd3a22e26e24c30135d" https://localhost:9443/oauth2/userinfo?schema=openid

the only output that result is:

> {"sub":"admin@carbon.super"}

I've follow all the WSO2IS guide for OAuth2 and for SAML2.
Please help!

Comment: How did you retrieve the access token?

Comment: with: curl -v -X POST --basic -u <client_key>:<client_secret> -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8' -k -d 'grant_type=client_credentials&scope=openid' https://localhost:9443/oauth2/token

Comment: Which user data would you expect to be returned when using client_credentials as a grant type?

Comment: I wrote it by default, but, with every user it returns always only "sub" fields. I also checked the claim mapping for http://wso2.org/oidc/claim (which is the default one) and all the fields are mapped.

Comment: I've followed this guide: https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS450/OpenID+Connect+Basic+Client+Profile+with+WSO2+Identity+Server for having all the user's attribute.

Comment: With the client credential grant type you can only get the info related to the user which created the application as the token is issued for the app rather than for a user. Since the app is created by the admin user here, you will get the sub as admin and additional claims of the admin if you have configured the service provider [[1]](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/Configuring+a+Service+Provider) to return more claims.

Comment: Yes, you're right, I've already try it (most likely in a wrong way). The problem is that every time that I manage _Claim Configuration_ of a _Service Provider_ the system give me error. For example I've added **http://wso2.org/claims/country** as a _Local claim_ and after ask it by the curl request. The response is always only "sub" and then I have problem with the service provider.

Comment: I,m sorry @Lucifer, I've tryed also with user_credentials, but it obviously don't return the token. Do you know how can I do?